# JQuery: How push City as key object and provider as child array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a key object array with the provider as a child array. here is my sample data, please help.

```
const data= [
{'city': 'LH','provider' : 'xyz'}
{'city': 'KR','provider' : 'ABC'}
{'city': 'LH','provider' : 'CDE'}
{'city': 'KR','provider' : 'xyz'}
{'city': 'LH','provider' : 'qwe'}
]
```

Want output Like:

```
result= [
{
'LH':{'xyz','CDE','qwe'},
'KR':{'ABC','QWE'}
}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This question does not include any jQuery, nor is the library needed for solving this.

First of all, your expected JSON is incorrect. You cannot have an object with only keys and no values. I believe you want an array. Also, you do not want to wrap the only object you have in an array, just keep the result an object. If you want to wrap your result in array, you may do so, after you are done reducing.

You can reduce the `data` by spreading the current `provider` across the value stored for each `city`.

```js
const
  data = [
    { 'city': 'LH', 'provider': 'xyz' },
    { 'city': 'KR', 'provider': 'ABC' },
    { 'city': 'LH', 'provider': 'CDE' },
    { 'city': 'KR', 'provider': 'xyz' },
    { 'city': 'LH', 'provider': 'qwe' }
  ],
  result = data.reduce((acc, { city, provider }) =>
    ({ ...acc, [city]: [...(acc[city] || []), provider] }), {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Here is the final result:

```json
{
  "LH": [ "xyz", "CDE", "qwe" ],
  "KR": [ "ABC", "xyz" ]
}
```

For more information on the techniques used above, check out:

- [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [Logical OR (||)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)

Here is a more verbose version, that avoids the ES5/ES6 features used above.

```js
var data = [
  { 'city': 'LH', 'provider': 'xyz' },
  { 'city': 'KR', 'provider': 'ABC' },
  { 'city': 'LH', 'provider': 'CDE' },
  { 'city': 'KR', 'provider': 'xyz' },
  { 'city': 'LH', 'provider': 'qwe' }
];

var result = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var current = data[i];
  var currentProviders = result[current.city];
  if (currentProviders == null) {
    currentProviders = [];
  }
  currentProviders.push(current.provider);
  result[current.city] = currentProviders;
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```